# Why can't blazor (WASM) use MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to read a file in blazor (wasm), but I get an error result. All MemoryStream bytes are 0. The code is as follows, and I'm sure the bytes have data (I printed them in the console):

```cs
Stream s = new MemoryStream(bytes);
s.Position = 0;
// debug
var br = new BinaryReader(s);
var bytes2 = new byte[s.Length];
br.Read(bytes2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', bytes2));// here is "0,0,0,...,0"
```

And, when I send the MemoryStream to the webapi, I get the data correctly.

Comment: Can you illustrate how you read the file. The code looks incomplete. Are you using [a file reader](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader) or how are you trying to read the file?

Comment: I'm sure this is a bug, see issues https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19907.
This can be solved by upgrading to. NET 5.

Thanks.